# Parked domain method to create multistore in magento

Tags: magento

I am looking to create multistore in magento....As i read that there are four ways to create multistore in magento:- Parked domain method,Add-on method,sub domain method & Sub-directory method...Can anybody tell me the difference between all these methods & what are the corresponding merits & demerits of each method...

Answer (score 0):

sub domain is new.shop.com whereas sub directory is shop.com/new

I use the directory method.  Google usually sees a subdomin as a separte site so for SEO sub domain is bad for small companies.  (If you can get good rankings for both site and subdomain its even better but takes twice the work).

Comment: Thanks Jon for updating!